# Michael Hartl Tutorial v. 3.2 Chapter 5.1 NoMethodError in Users#new Line 4

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie and I'm working slowly through Hartl. Just started on Ch5. Got to 5.1 and added the new styling code into application.html.erb and i'm getting "NoMethodError in Static_pages#home in the browser".

Here's the terminal readout:

```
Started GET "/static_pages/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-31 14:02:03 +0100
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x007f865b6a0160>:0x007f865b5faad0>):
    1: <!DOCTYPE html>
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4: <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    6: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2520617125150382104_70107517560200'


  Rendered /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/Lagaspi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (9.1ms)
```

The static_pages_controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Nothing has changed from successfully completing Ch.3. So I went back, worked Ch.3 again, with all the test passes green and all the browser tests OK I jumped back into Ch.5. Cut and pasted Hartls new code into views/layouts/application.html.erb , saved the file and I'm getting the same No Method Error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `full_title` helper is introduced right at the start of [Chapter 4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#top).